# Writing $a^2b^0c^0+a^0b^2c^0+a^0b^0c^2+a^1b^1c^0+a^1b^0c^1+a^0b^1c^1$ using $\sum$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, notation, combinations

$$a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+ac+bc$$
$$=a^2b^0c^0+a^0b^2c^0+a^0b^0c^2+a^1b^1c^0+a^1b^0c^1+a^0b^1c^1$$

Been messing around with some probability stuff and that popped up. I couldn't figure out how to write it in summation form so I can generalize it for when the sum of the exponents isn't just 2.

Answer (score 5):

$$\sum_{\substack{i,j,k\ge0\\ i+j+k=2}}\mkern-9mua^i b^j c^k$$
seems to be what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

Let us call the elements $a_1,a_2$ and $a_3$ instead of $a,b$ and $c$. Then we can write $$\sum_{\substack{i_1,i_2,i_3\ge0\\ i_1+i_2+i_3=2}}\mkern-9mu a_1^{i_1} a_2^{i_2} a_3^{i_3}$$ for the sum that you are regarding. The reason to rename the elements is that you can also state it in terms of multi index notation then if you want to.

Edit: Let me elaborate on the latter.  If we write $a = (a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and $i = (i_1,i_2,i_3)$ and consider $a^i$ as $a_1^{i_1} a_2^{i_2} a_3^{i_3}$ (so we work entrywise), then we can express the sum as $$\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}_2^3} a^i,$$ where $\mathbb{N}_2^3 = \lbrace (i_1,i_2,i_3) \in \mathbb{N}^3 \mid i_1 +i_2 +i_3 = 2 \rbrace$.

Comment: +1. Could you expand on what you mean by "multi-index notation"? What's the problem with $$\sum_{\substack{i_1,i_2,i_3\ge0\\ i_1+i_2+i_3=2}}\mkern-9mu a^{i_1} b^{i_2} c^{i_3}$$?

Comment: I added it to my answer. Oh and there is no problem. It is just that people like different notations so it is good to present some variety.

Answer (score 1):

For example : try $$\sum \{ a^ib^jc^k: i,j,k \in \Bbb N, i+j+k=2\}$$

But what does writing such an expression this way buy you?

Comment: The specific thing I'm trying to figure out was the probability that $n$ people, choosing out of $k$ options, would end up picking all of the options and this pattern shows up. When you have n people, you get $\sum\{(\frac{1}{k})^{i_1}(\frac{2}{k})^{i_2} ... (\frac{k-1}{k})^{i_{k-1}}, i_1+i_2+ ... + i_{k-1} = n-k\}$

Comment: @IgorRigolonLa-CavaVeiga: This makes your question the wrong question. And that's why the ask-question page explicitly tells you [how to ask a good question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960), which includes providing the reason for your interest in the question. In your case, it is trivially solved by the principle of inclusion and exclusion.

Comment: @user21820 Yes, sorry, you're right, I'll be sure to follow that in the future. How could I use that principle to solve this problem though? And would the answer also be given in terms of these sorts of summations over a whole set of combinations of many variables?

Comment: @IgorRigolonLa-CavaVeiga: I suggest you take a look at the wikipedia article on inclusion-exclusion, and study carefully the example about derangements. Exactly the same counting strategy applies here, and the result should be a single summation over one variable.

Answer (score 0):

Consider

$$\frac12\left(\sum_i x_i\right)^2+\frac12\sum_i x_i^2.$$

This will not generalize easily, though.